# Cone of vision in perspective drawing

Tags: drawing, linear-perspective

I have referred to most online resources to help myself understand the concept of **cone of vision** in perspective drawing and I am still confused and don't fully understand the concept.

Can someone help me understand the cone of vision?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts SE. Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help], especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to be more specific to get a specific answer. What exactly is it you don't understand or struggle with? What have you tried that didn't work? Maybe you can link to a specific source and ask for clarification of a certain paragraph. As it stand this question in unclear and too broad and might get closed.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, but a simple Google search gave me a very clear answer. The `cone of vision` is the spatial volume seen by a (dimensionless) observer inside an angle of 60<sup>o</sup>.

To "calculate" the envelope (margin) of the [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone), you "draw" all the lines originating at the observer and being at an angle of 30<sup>o</sup> away from the line of sight.

Everything outside this cone is considered "out-of-sight".

Notes:

1. For humans (and most living creatures possessing vision), there are two distinct cones of vision, one for each eye. The relative position of the two  cones varies greatly, depending on the relative position of the eyes (e.g., both eyes to the front, like humans, or eyes to the sides, lie fish). Eye movement leads to movement of the cone of vision.
2. For how to successfully use the concept of "cone of vision" in drawing, architecture or anything else, you need to get further knowledge on all these subjects.